How to implement real-time updates in Editor.js using Pusher?
I am currently working on integrating real-time capabilities into an Editor.js instance in a TypeScript project. My goal is to ensure that any changes made to blocks (like adding, deleting, or updating) are reflected instantly across different devices connected to the site without requiring user authentication.
here is the source code of editorjs: https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js
I should configure the event listeners but on DOM i don't know if there anyone for help and thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
